# How to delegate instantiation of constructor by classtype?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have several classes that extend a `BaseClass`. Now I want to define an active class statically in a `DelegatorContext`, and each object creation should be based on the active context.

Example:

```
class BaseClass {
    String firstname, lastname;
}

class FirstClas extends BaseClass {}
class SndClass extends BaseClass {}

class DelegatorContext {
    public static BaseClass activeClass;
}

class Delegator {
    BaseClass create(String firstname, String lastname) {
        return DelegatorContext.activeClass instanceof FirstClass
          ? new FirstClass(firstname, lastname) : new SndClass(firstname, lastname);
    }
}
```

The example would get even more boilerplate if more entities are introduced extending `BaseClass`.

Is there a better pattern for my kind of problem? Maybe even with Java8 and `Functions`? Or Generics?

I'm using this construct for beeing able to switch the implementation at runtime...

Comment: You should probably use a `Class` object rather than an actual instance of the required class. But you do have to make sure each of the subclasses has a two-string-parameter constructor, which you didn't in the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you mean something like this:

```
interface BaseClassFactory {
    BaseClass create(String firstname, String lastname);
}
class DelegatorContext {
    public static BaseClassFactory active;
}
```

…

```
DelegatorContext.active=FirstClass::new;
```

…

```
DelegatorContext.active=SndClass::new;
```

which requires that all subclasses have a constructor with the same signature, matching the signature of the factory interface (and interestingly gives an example to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29386441/2711488))

You don’t really need the other factory class but for completeness, it would be:

```
class Delegator {
    BaseClass create(String firstname, String lastname) {
        return DelegatorContext.active.create(firstname, lastname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `FirstClass::new` gives the following error: `The target type of this expression must be a functional interface`

Comment: Check that `FirstClass::new` is assigned to a variable of the type `BaseClassFactory` as shown in my answer. `BaseClassFactory` should consist of a single `abstract` method as shown; you may add `@FunctionalInterface` to get compiler feedback if it doesn’t meet the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I understand it now and it work as expected!

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `DelegatorContext` generic with a type-parameter that's a subclass of `BaseClass`.

Also, the `activeClass` should not be `static` and an additional `Class<T>` member should be introduced to hold the `Class` info about the `activeClass`.

It will be used in order to instantiate the correct subclass:

```
class DelegatorContext<T extends BaseClass> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public T activeClass;

    private DelegatorContext(Class<T> clazz) { 
         this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T createInstance(String firstname, String secondname) {
        activeClass = clazz.newInstance();
        activeClass.setFirstName(firstname);
        activeClass.setSecondName(secondname);
        return activeClass;
    }

    public static <T extends BaseClass> DelegatorContext<T> of(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new DelegatorContext<T>(clazz);
    }
}
```

Having this, you can do:

```
<T extends BaseClass> T create(Class<T> clazz, String firstname, String lastname) {
    return DelegatorContext.of(clazz).createInstance(firstname, lastname);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to switch the active class at runtime with this?

Comment: Yes, you can always provide a setter for the `clazz`. However, when changing the active class, you have to make sure the `activeClass` changes correctly. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: That’s how I would do it *before* Java 8…

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you'll be best off using an enum here:

```
enum DelegatorContext {
    First {
        @Override
        BaseClass instantiate(String firstName, String lastName) {
            return new FirstClass(firstName, lastName);
        }
    },
    Second{
        @Override
        BaseClass instantiate(String firstName, String lastName) {
            return new SecondClass(firstName, lastName);
        }
    };

    static Context defaultContext;
    abstract BaseClass instantiate(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```